# How to "un-git-ify" my HD

Tags: git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree

So a few months ago, I apparently created a local repository, in the form of my user folder on my hard drive. I did this using some fool's attempt at a Git101 documentation, and as a result I currently have 168,352 pending/unstated changes. Is there a way to not only remove the git bookmark (from source tree), but also remove all of the .git* files from each folder?

Obviously, my goal is **not** to remove the contents from my user folder... as that would be bad.

Comment: Git doesn't put `.git` folders in each folder, it only does so for the root folder of the repository.

Answer (score 3):

If you did `git init` in the root of your user folder, it should have only created a `.git` folder in that folder itself.

You can remove it without damaging your actual files by executing the following in a terminal from your home folder:

```
rm -rf ~/.git/
```

Comment: Thank you this was so helpful. Getting back into Git and found this little charm on my HD. :/

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if `~/.git` exists. If it does, you can delete, rename or move it to destroy the repository (won't affect your working copy, i.e. your home folder). Git only has a single `.git` directory per repository (unlike SVN or CVS, which may have one RCS directory in each working copy directory)